# VBA scraping code permission denied error

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I was trying to scrape some data from a  website using VBA. i have written following code. Sometimes it opens the final page and sometimes it does not. When it opens the final Page, it throws an error saying "Permission denied". Code is as following:

```
Sub hullByAshish()
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim ElementCol As Object
Dim Link As Object
Dim appIE As Object
Dim a As String
Dim i As Long
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
a = "ASDETA"
With appIE
    .Navigate "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/search/all/keyword:" & a
    .Visible = True
End With
Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop
Set html = appIE.document
Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each Link In ElementCol
If Link.innerHTML = "ASDETA" Then
'MsgBox "yahoo"
Link.Click
End If
Next Link
End Sub
```

Comment: add a `readystate` complete check to appIE

Comment: @Nathan_Sav  can you please help me on how to do that?

Comment: seeing as you gave it 2 minutes :) `Do While appIE.Busy and appIE.Readystate<>READYSTATE_COMPLETE`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268229(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Which is the line the error in? Please edit your question and add description what is the expected output.